# Error: Node.js module defined by file index.js is expected to export function named xxxx

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-contacts-api

Hello there dev community. I´m trying to debug a firebase function and being trying using several tutorials, but with no success...

I´ve tried
(https://medium.com/@mwebler/debugging-firebase-functions-with-vs-code-3afab528bb36)
(https://medium.com/@david_mccoy/build-and-debug-firebase-functions-in-vscode-73efb76166cf)

My purpose is to get google contacts.

## functions/index.js

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const oauthUserCredential = require('./oauthUserCredential.json')
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2

const key = require('./serviceAccountKey.json')
const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts')

exports.getGoogleContacts = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  const requestingUser = data.requestingUser
  console.log('getGoogleContacts-requestingUser', requestingUser)


  const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    'client_id',
    'client_secret',
    'http://localhost:5000/xxx-xxx/us-central1/OAuthCallbackUrl'
  );


  const contacts = google.people({
    version: 'v1',
    auth: oauth2Client,
  });

  console.log('contacts ?', contacts)

    (async () => {
      const { data: groups } = await contacts.people.get({
        resourceName: 'contactGroups',
      });
      console.log('Contact Groups:\n', groups);

    })()


  jwt.authorize((err, response) => {
    console.log('inside authorize')
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      response.end();
      return;
    }

    // Make an authorized request to list contacts.
    contacts.people.connections.list({
      auth: authClient,
      resourceName: 'people/me'
    }, function (err, resp) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        response.end();
        return;
      }

      console.log("Success");
      console.log(resp);
      response.send(resp);
    });

  });

  // this is another approach I´ve tried, but it´s also not working

  const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2(
    oauthUserCredential.web.client_id,
    oauthUserCredential.web.client_secret,
    oauthUserCredential.web.redirect_uris,
)

oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: oauthUserCredential.refresh_token
})
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('[INSIDE PEOPLE CONNECTIONS]')
    contacts.people.connections.list({
        auth: oauth2Client //authetication object generated in step-3
    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('contacts.people.connections error')
            console.log(err)
            reject(new Error(err))
        } else if (response) {
            console.log('contacts.people.connections response')
            console.log(response)
            resolve(response)
        }
    });
})
    .then(result => { return { found: result } })
    .catch(err => { return { error: err } })


})
```

I´ve tried several different approachs and followed different tutorials
([Using Google People API with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553211/using-google-people-api-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase))
(https://flaviocopes.com/google-api-authentication/)
(https://medium.com/@smccartney09/integrating-firebase-cloud-functions-with-google-calendar-api-9a5ac042e869)
(https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-oauth-gmail)

but none of them show clearly how could I get my contacts list.
I was able to use a client side code by following this tutorial (https://labs.magnet.me/nerds/2015/05/11/importing-google-contacts-with-javascript.html)
but I thought that living the client_id, client_secret and apiKey exposed in the client side would be a security problem...

[image]

I´m submitting also a tutorial request to make it very clear how to get contacts list from google account using firebase functions.

Answer (score 0):

The Error you are receiving is because the cloud function cannot find the function named xxxx to execute, as you have not defined any function named xxxx in the index.js file.

Your Cloud Function to execute name, according to the error message is xxxx but the function that you are calling in index.js is getGoogleContacts. Please make sure that these names are the same, for example **change getGoogleContacts to xxxx or change function to execute to getGoogleContacts**